# How do you represent ideas and concepts visually?

Tags: design-principles

Are there any books (or articles, websites etc..) that talk about the subject of "translating" ideas and concepts into graphics? I would like to learn about this and get some new ideas to help me as a beginning graphic designer.

Thank you in advance for any useful resources you can provide me with.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

What a nice question. It made me think a lot.

Even though I'm not a Graphic Designer, I love making designs and it's part of my full time job!
I'm pretty sure you'll get your question answered more specifically with book names and authors about Creative Thinking, but here's my advise.

**Abstraction is everything**. The key is to fully understand the design problem you're facing.
Your experience (yeah, I mean life experiences), your design style and the target audience profile (and taste), will lead to the ideal representation of the idea. Next problem you'll be facing is "**where**" are you drawing that design...Digital, Press? Installation?...

So here's the book I would recommend you: *Grid Systems in Graphic Design by Josef Müller-Brockmann*.

Learn as much as you can about Grid Systems, It will help you a lot!

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, Neph, Thank you for your response and for the suggestion! I'll take a look at that book.